# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (100,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, output, kaggle

I need to build an inception module in `keras` and train `cifar100` data set with that.
using the below code:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar100

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0

from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
from keras.layers import Input
input_img = Input(shape = (32, 32,3))
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
tower_1 = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
tower_1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_1)
tower_2 = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
tower_2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_2)
tower_3 = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(input_img)
tower_3 = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_3)
output = keras.layers.concatenate([tower_1, tower_2, tower_3], axis = 3)

from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
output = Flatten()(output)
out    = Dense(100, activation='softmax')(output)
from keras.models import Model
model = Model(inputs = input_img, outputs = out)

#print model.summary()

from keras.optimizers import SGD
epochs = 30
lrate = 0.01
decay = lrate/epochs
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=32)
   # scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    #print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

I get the below value error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (100,)

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
        136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
        137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
    --> 138                             str(data_shape))
        139     return data
        140
```

using kaggle kernel script.
can anybody tell what is wrong?

Comment: I ran your code and couldn't reproduce your error. I'm using Keras 2.2.4 running on the docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3

Comment: @JulianoSAssine, thanks for your time. I have access to kaggle only for gpu based environment; if you could run the same on that and can identify anything.

Comment: @JulianoSAssine, can you share screenshot of output or any log file? Even I have done correctly, couldn't get output. If you can share please, that will complete my task.

Comment: Sorry, never used the Kaggle environment, but I suggest you try it on [google collab](https://colab.research.google.com), you can go to Edit->Notebook Settings->Hardware Accelerator and choose GPU, I am able to run your code there as well

Comment: @JulianoSAssine, tried collab as well, same error; I was asking if you could share log files from your system with platform you are using.